# Is 'what's [something] doing here' a natural expression?

Tags: expressions, sentence-usage, sentence

Let me first explain the context here. In the sixth episode of *Golden Kamuy 4*, an [Ainu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ainu_people) guy Ariko works as a spy for a samurai gang in a hunt for a gold treasure. Ariko wants to steal the treasure maps from a lieutenant at night. When he opens the box in which he saw the lieutenant locked the maps, he only finds a knife, which is a surprise to him. (The lieutenant was cautious enough to figure out Ariko had become a spy, so he hid the map somewhere else in advance.) So, he says,

> What's this makiri doing here?

Note: makiri is some hand-made knife seen in the Ainu culture.
[image]

I think the sentence means 'what happens? Why is the makiri here? Where are the maps?' Nevertheless, this expression sounds kind of weird to me. Is it natural?

Comment: It doesn't mean speaker is asking the ***literal*** question *(What **activity** is this makiri performing?).* It's an *idiomatic* usage, meaning ***Why** is it here?* - usually with the strong implication that speaker wouldn't expect to find a makiri in such a context (it's "out of place").

Comment: Note that this *idiomatic* sense normally only occurs when ***doing*** is followed by an ***adverb of place*** (such as ***here, there, on the floor,...***). Suppose you came in to work on a Sunday and you were surprised to find John there, because he usually only works Monday to Friday. The question *What's John doing here?* would usually be that idiomatic sense *(**Why** is he here?)* - but *What's John doing **today**?* (or the same with no adverb at all) would normally be a *literal* question *(What **activities** is he carrying out here today?)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's a natural expression.

In this context 'doing' means 'existing', not asking what activity is being undertaken.

If the word or phrase following 'doing' is a specifier of  place  (here/there/in Italy), then:

*"What is [x] doing [specifier]"*

Means : Why is [X] [here/there/at the north pole].

Further to your question:

If it makes sense for a particular [X] : What activity is [X] undertaking [here/there/at the north pole].

If the word or phrase following 'doing' is a specifier of  time (now/at ten/tomorrow), then:

*"What is [x] doing [specifier]"*

Means : What purpose does [X] have, or what activity is [X] undertaking now/at ten/tomorrow.

Comment: No, *in this context*, this question can only mean, "Why is this knife here?", never "What activity is this knife performing?". The knife clearly isn't performing any activity -- it's just sitting there, and the speaker is showing surprise that the knife is there, not an inquiry about its activity. The expression "What is X doing here" is ambiguous without a context, but with a context, it's crystal clear.

Comment: @gotube Agreed. - I was thinking about the context with all types of words (including people), but that is unclear. Answer edited.

Comment: Cool. Downvote removed. :) BUT the rest of your sentence about other possible meanings of the structure that do not apply to the OP's context aren't necessary. Including them without making this clear could still be confusing. It's not at all clear that your answer actually ends at your second sentence, and the rest of your answer doesn't apply to this context at all. A student will likely read that and try to figure out how it applies to their question.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, your answer format style kind of reminds me of BCLC.

Comment: @gotube I've edited that to make it clear. Could you cast your eye over it, please?

Comment: @Michael I've no idea what particular initialism you mean by BCLC. Is it some kind of compluer language syntax specification system?

Comment: Never mind. It's just the name of a user.